# update the image plane distance in Fresnel transform

Tags: compressive-sensing

I have performed reconstruction of images in Fresnel transform using a desired algorithm. Now the aim is to find an optimal value of image plane distance at which the reconstruction is accurate. I have formulated the problem as below:

||X_recon - X*e^{ax^2}.e{-bx^2}*e{cx^2}||_2^2 such that ||c||<=1

here X_recon = reconstructed image in F domain
ax bx are known
we need to find c=image plane distance and the real X (time-domain).

Is the formulation correct